# How to use a Wizard in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, wizard

Here is my code:

```
    class StudentWizard(models.TransientModel):
        _name = 'student.wizard'

        def _get_default_students(self):
            return self.env['ecole.partner.school'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_ids'))

        student_ids = fields.Many2many('ecole.partner.school', String="Student", default=_get_default_students)
        school_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.establishment",
                                      string="Etablissement Scolaire",
                                      required=True)
        school_year = fields.Many2one(string='Période',
                                      ondelete='SET NULL',
                                      comodel_name="ecole.partner.school.years",
                                      required=True)
        school_level = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.grade",
                                       string="Niveau Scolaire",
                                       required=True)
        #level = fields.Char('Level')

        api.multi
        def set_student_level(self):
            for record in self:
                if record.student_ids:
                    for student in record.student_ids:
                        update_student = self.env['ecole.partner.school']
                        partner_id = update_student.partner_id
                        school_year = update_student.school_year
                        school_name = update_student.school_name
                        half_pension = update_student.half_pension
                        nursery = update_student.nursery

                        student.school_year = school_year
                        student.school_level = self.school_level
                        student.school_name = school_name

                        vals = {'partner_id': partner_id, 'nursery': nursery}
                        res = update_student.create(vals)

                    return res

My View:

        <act_window id="student_wizard_action" name="Mise à jour des élèves" res_model="student.wizard"
                    src_model="ecole.partner.school"
                    view_mode="form" target="new" multi="True"/>

        <record id="student_wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">student Marks Views</field>
            <field name="model">student.wizard</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <group>
                        <field name="student_ids" widget="many2many_list"/>
                        <field name="school_name"/>
                        <field name="school_year"/>
                        <field name="school_level"/>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="set_student_level" string="Passage au niveau suivant" class="oe_right oe_highlight"
                                type="object"/>
                        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_right" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I like to create a new record in my model school.partner.school and the problem is that the model which i have created was empty.I can't understand why.

Comment: can you please explain it more!! You wanted to save the record of the transient model?

Comment: Not necessarily. With the help of a button, I want to update the value of a field without overwriting the old value to keep a history. And I do not know how to do it. I am a beginner with Odoo

Comment: First of all, if it's a transient model then data will store temporarily in the database. I think you wanted to create data in the model name 'ecole.partner.school' .. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to update them in the model "ecole.partner.school". But there are several values ​​to update. I would at least like to understand for a value like for example "school_name"

Comment: @VishalKhichadiya apologies I rejected your edit by mistake! It should be approved by the other reviewers (I hope).

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: corrected formatting

Comment: I just understood that it's just a TransientModel assistant and that after a while, the base is erased and that's not what I want to do. I wish the update stays! It would just take a little help to understand an update function. –

Answer (score 0):

**For update the record you have to find it first!!**

model 'ecole.partner.school' must not be the Transient model.

Please create domain that suits for your requirement instead of [].

```
@api.multi
def set_student_level(self):
    domain = []

    for record in self:
        for student in record.student_ids:
            update_student = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search(domain,limit=1)
            if update_student:
                partner_id = update_student.partner_id
                school_year = update_student.school_year
                school_name = update_student.school_name
                half_pension = update_student.half_pension
                nursery = update_student.nursery
                student.school_year = school_year
                student.school_level = self.school_level
                student.school_name = school_name
                vals = {'partner_id': partner_id, 'nursery': nursery}
                res = update_student.create(vals)
    return True
```

Comment: The result is the same, see photo for example. Maybe my variable "nursery = update_student.nursery" is wrong? In this variable I want to retrieve the value of "nursery" per selected student to copy them with the create () method. Thank you

Comment: I just understood that it's just a TransientModel assistant and that after a while, the base is erased and that's not what I want to do. I wish the update stays! It would just take a little help to understand an update function.

Comment: exactly as I mentioned before in a comment that TransientModel store temporary data in odoo.

Comment: I replaced TransientModel with Model. Comment update without erasing the last record?

Comment: this  3 line 
student.school_year = school_year , 
                student.school_level = self.school_level and
                student.school_name = school_name are updating your last record if you don't want to update it please remove it from code.

Comment: and please remove your own ans form the post.